# dowload app engine ndb entities via bulk exporter / bulk uploader

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Context:

My model classes inherit from a base class:

```
class BaseModel(ndb.model):
  # commom fields and methods

class SpecificModel(BaseModel):
  # specific fields and methods
```

Problem:

I want to export the SpecificModel entities using the [appengine bulkuploader service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata).

I have the defined the config file (data_loader.py):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('.') ## this is to ensure that it finds the file 'models.py'
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.tools import bulkloader
from models import *

class SpecificModelExporter(bulkloader.Exporter):
  def __init__(self):
    bulkloader.Exporter.__init__(self, 'SpecificModel',
                                 [('fieldOne', str, None),
                                  ('fieldTwo', str, None)
                                 ])

    exporters = [ SpecificModelExporter ]
```

I use the following command to download data:

```
  appcfg.py download_data --config_file=data_loader.py --filename=data.csv --kind=SpecificModel --url=http://url.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api
```

When I try to download the data I get the following **error**:

```
google.appengine.ext.db.KindError: No implementation for kind 'SpecificModel'
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py?r=302#949):

Your model will be looked up in `GetImplementationClass` via

```
implementation_class = db.class_for_kind(kind_or_class_key)
```

but the registry of `db` models will not include any `ndb` models you've defined. A similar registry is created in `ndb.Model._kind_map` and any `db` models you had defined would not be found there.

**NOTE:** As far [as I can tell](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list?q=bulkloader%20ndb) there is no corresponding issue/feature request asking for `ndb` support in the bulk loader or an equivalent `ndb` bulk loader. It may be worth filing one and starring it.

Comment: Thanks I filed an issue on http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/issues/detail?id=224

Comment: Great! I just may take up this fix :)

Comment: @bossylobster , currently is bulk uploader available for use with ndb models?

Comment: Any update to this issue? From the issue that Marco created, it doesn't look like there has been any progress :(